# Unix: merge many files, while deleting first line of all files

Tags: bash, merge

I have >100 files that I need to merge, but for each file the first line has to be removed. What is the most efficient way to do this under Unix? I suspect it's probably a command using *cat* and *sed '1d'*. All files have the same extension and are in the same folder, so we probably could use *.extension to point to the files. Many thanks!

Comment: For removing the first line, see e.g. [`tail`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) (`tail -n +2 file`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude One should use `tail -q -n +2 file`, to avoid output of headers giving file names.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Assuming your filenames are sorted in the order you want your files appended, you can use:

```
ls *.extension | xargs -n 1 tail -n +2
```

EDIT: After Sorin and Gilles comments about the possible dangers of piping **ls** output, you could use:

```
find . -name "*.extension" | xargs -n 1 tail -n +2
```

Comment: -1 for piping ls output to something, ls is not designed to do that, use find

Comment: In what circumstance would this be bad Sorin?

Comment: Can you give a link for possible problems with piping ls output? Thanks

Comment: The above reference compares parsing the output of `ls` to doing internal string manipulation like `for x in *.txt`. It does not compare parsing the output of `ls` to parsing the output of `find`. Both are "bad" according to the same logic.

Comment: The reference does mention `find` but it recommends using the GNU `find` extensions to output null terminated strings.  Replacing `ls` with a plain old `find` is completely pointless.

Comment: If I do something like: `find . -name "*.csv" | xargs -n 1 tail -n +2 > output.extension` then my `output.csv` file gets included in the `find . -name "*.csv"` and as a result the output file reads itself and then outputs to itself again. Is there a way to avoid this other than to make the output file not a `.csv` file?

Answer (score 20):

Everyone has to be complicated. This is really easy:

```
tail -q -n +2 file1 file2 file3
```

And so on. If you have a large number of files you can load them in to an array first:

```
list=(file1 file2 file3)
tail -q -n +2 "${list[@]}"
```

All the files with a given extension in the current directory?

```
list=(*.extension)
tail -q -n +2 "${list[@]}"
```

Or just

```
tail -q -n +2 *.extension
```

Comment: I attempted `tail -n +2 *.extension`. The version of tail I'm using returns `tail: Can only process one file at a time.` so that explains the more complicated answers.

Answer (score 6):

Just append each file after removing the first line.

```
#!/bin/bash

DEST=/tmp/out
FILES=space separated list of files

echo "" >$DEST
for FILE in $FILES
do
    sed -e'1d' $FILE >>$DEST
done
```

Answer (score 3):

`tail` outputs the last lines of a file. You can tell it how many lines to print, or how many lines to omit at the beginning (`-n +N` where N is the number of the first line to print, counting from 1 — so `+2` omits one line). With GNU utilities (i.e. under Linux or Cygwin), FreeBSD or other systems that have the `-q` option:

```
tail -q -n +2 *.extension
```

`tail` prints a header before each file, and `-q` is not standard. If your implementation doesn't have it, or to be portable, you need to iterate over the files.

```
for x in *.extension; do tail -n +2 <"$x"; done
```

Alternatively, you can call Awk, which has a way to identify the first line of each file. This is likely to be faster if you have a lot of small files and slower if you have many large files.

```
awk 'FNR != 1' *.extension
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -1 file*.txt | xargs nawk 'FNR!=1'
```