# How to output merge to file?

Tags: bash, merge

I have been following the directions to concatenate files in a directory as directed in this post: [Unix: merge many files, while deleting first line of all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103619/unix-merge-many-files-while-deleting-first-line-of-all-files), but it is not working correctly. To sum, this is the command being used:

```
find . -name "*.extension" | xargs -n 1 tail -n +2
```

I attempt to attach a name to this file and redirect like this:

```
find . -name "*.extension" | xargs -n 1 tail -n +2 > concatenated.csv
```

but this only grabs the first file. Am I doing something wrong? I am very unfamiliar with these commands.

Comment: This should work fine if none of your filenames have whitespace or quotes in them. Do you get any error messages? does `find . -name "*.extension"` output all the files you expect?

Comment: They do have whitespace and I get errors. Do I just need to remove the whitespace?

Comment: You have two working answers below that do not require renaming. Friendly tip for the future: include any error messages you get, as this make it much easier to determine what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your files contain whitespace or quotes, which xargs by default doesn't like. If you use the GNU versions of find and xargs, you can use

```
find . -name "*.extension" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 tail -n +2 > concatenated.csv
```

to safely handle all file names.

Comment: I also found that if you are going to use this method you must either place the output in a different directory or it will add the already concatenated file to itself. Just a heads up on that.

Comment: Definitely a good point. You can exclude the output with `-name "*.csv" ! -name "concatenated.csv" -print0"` if you want to write to the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple command like this, you can skip `xargs` and just use the `-execdir` primary:

```
find . -name "*.extension" -execdir tail -n +2 '{}' \; > concatenated.csv
```

Inspired by Kevin's answer, you can also use

```
find . -name "*.extension" -execdir tail -q -n +2 '{}' + > concatenated.csv
```

which will only run `tail` one time on all the files, instead of once per file.

Comment: I couldn't get this one to work. It tells me that `-execdir` is not a valid predicate.

Comment: Hm, that's odd. You can try with `-exec` as well, which may be more standard. In this example, there should be no difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `tail` on each file individually, you may want to use another tool that can process more files at once. e.g. `awk`:

```
find . -name '*.extension' -exec awk 'FNR > 1' + >concatenated.csv
```

Comment: You can do the same with `tail -q` (which I wouldn't have thought to check if you hadn't posted this answer, so +1).